# Python threading.Timer return value

Tags: python, recursion

I'm using the threading.Timer() in Python for integration of Gyroscope values. 
The turn function is called from leftTurn(). Now I want to return a True to leftTurn() when the maximum angle is reached. My problem is the recursion inside turn(). Is it somehow possible to  let leftTurn() know when the turn is completed?

```
class navigation():

    def __init__(self):
        self.mpu = mpu6050(0x68)

    def getOffset(self):
        gyro_data = self.mpu.get_gyro_data()
        offset = abs(gyro_data['z'])
        return offset

    def turn(self, angle,offset,maxAngle):
        gyro_data = self.mpu.get_gyro_data()    
        gyroZ = abs(gyro_data['z'])
        angle = abs(angle + (gyroZ-offset)*0.01)

        if angle < maxAngle:        
            threading.Timer(0.001, self.turn, [angle,offset,maxAngle]).start()
        else:
            motor().stop()
            return True





class motor():

    ...

    def leftTurn(self, maxAngle):
        self.left()
        offset = navigation().getOffset()
        navigation().turn(0,offset,maxAngle)
```

Comment: To you want to wait in `leftTurn` for `turn` to finish?

Comment: Yes in leftTurn I want to wait for turn to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class navigation():

def __init__(self):
    self.mpu = mpu6050(0x68)

def getOffset(self):
    gyro_data = self.mpu.get_gyro_data()
    offset = abs(gyro_data['z'])
    return offset

def turn(self, angle,offset,maxAngle):
    gyro_data = self.mpu.get_gyro_data()    
    gyroZ = abs(gyro_data['z'])
    angle = abs(angle + (gyroZ-offset)*0.01)

    if angle < maxAngle:        
        thread = threading.Timer(0.001, self.turn, [angle,offset,maxAngle])
        thread.start()  # Start the thread
        thread.join()  # >ait for the thread to end
        return True
    else:
        motor().stop()
        return True
```

Because you don't need the return value of `turn` and you just want to know of the thread have ended you can use [Thread.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) to wait for a thread to end.

> Timer is a subclass of Thread

Comment: I get the error : thread = threading.Timer(0.001, self.turn [angle,offset,maxAngle]).start()
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: By bad I removed a comma by mistake: `thread = threading.Timer(0.001, self.turn, [angle,offset,maxAngle]).start()`. Note you can use ` to highlight code text.

Comment: Thank you so far for your solution it's working. Just reaching maximum of threads

Answer (score 0):

As always, you should try to replace recursion with loop. In this case I would do it like this:

```
def turn(self, angle, offset, maxAngle):
    while angle < maxAngle:
        threading.wait(0.001)
        gyro_data = self.mpu.get_gyro_data()    
        gyroZ = abs(gyro_data['z'])
        angle = abs(angle + (gyroZ-offset)*0.01)
    else:
        motor().stop()
        return True
```

I wonder why you use `threading` in your original code and whether you actually need to use it anyway, however.

Comment: Why should he replace recursion with loop?

Comment: @YassineFaris, OP said "My problem is the recursion inside turn()", so I assume OP faced `maximum recursion depth` error.

Comment: I don't mind to replace the threading, but how I can let the function then wait 0.001ms?

Comment: If you need blocking wait, you should `import time` and `time.sleep(0.001)`.